# Vim and Latex-Suite

Tags: vim

I'm using latexsuite with vim and I am currently editing files that have the form

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\input{header.tex}
\item blah
\input{footer.tex}
```

The problem is that the \begin{document} declaration is in the header.tex file, so that when I try to use latexsuite macros, it thinks I'm in the preamble. Is there any way to force latexsuite to behave as though it is in the body of the document? (also, if you're confused, the header.tex file also starts a list environment, hence the \item in the body.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a practical solution, why don't you move the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` lines out of `header.tex` and `footer.tex` templates and into each actual document? I understand you may be trying to follow the DRY principle, but for a TeX file that's honestly intended to be compiled as a document, I feel that these two tags should actually be in that document, not sourced from another TeX file.

Comment: I see your point, but I was really trying to avoid that because part of the header file is \begin{document} \begin{main-list}, so there is more to it. The reason I'm doing it this way is that I wanted a quick way to make a uniform style for all my school work (which is almost always a list of problems) that could be easily changed; if you have any other suggestions, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to develop a `sty` or `cls` file.

Comment: I should mention, try also asking this question on the [TeX-LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). More LaTeX experts hang out there these days.